# showing result on nth page on android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Assume i have five screens (ie.five activities). First activity is going to return some values on textview on the same page.But i want to show only that answer on page number five(ie.fifth screen).But the concept has written on the first's page.

How to achieve this concept.I have googled it as per my knowledge but still seeking.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not enough information here to really answer this, if you are trying to persist a small amount of data that is used in an activity not directly started by your first activity you could use shared preferences, if the data is consumed then remove it in your fifth page

Comment: Do you want to show the result of Activity 1 in Activity N ?

Comment: yes, Absolutely correct mr.abbas